# Linux Kernel: work->entry needs to be emptied before the work can be inserted to the work queue

Tags: c, linux, kernel

As my understanding, the [__queue_work](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L1418) function adds a work to the work queue. This function requires the work object to have an empty list of other works: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L1499.

The `work->entry` is a double link list of works.

My question is that why does the Linux kernel considers this empty link list as `work` is not in the work queue? What is the advantage of this design?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a doubly-linked-list has two pointers for each item. And the list itself also has two pointers, for the start and end. *In Linux, they are the same thing.* An item that's not in a list, is the same as a list that contains no items.

The work->entry is the work's item in the list. If it's not empty, the work is already in the list. Adding it to the list *again* is a mistake.